getting IInsufficient privileges to complete the operation. For Rest Password
var client = graph.GetGraphClient();

try
{
    //get existing user
    var user = await GetGraphUser(userId, cancellationToken);

    //Ensure the PasswordProfile exists before attempting to update the password
    if (user.PasswordProfile == null)
    {
        user.PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
        {
            Password = newPassword,
            ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true
        };
    }
    else
    {
        // Update the password if PasswordProfile is present
        user.PasswordProfile.Password = newPassword;
        user.PasswordProfile.ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true;
    }
    await client.Users[userId].PatchAsync(user, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
catch (Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError ex)
{
    GraphExceptionsHandler.Handle(ex);
}

This is my code I want to reset the password of user in entraId using graph client. But I am getting error Insufficient privileges. I tried lot of permissions
I tried all these permissions



If you are authenticated on behalf of a user, the signed-in user must have at least User Administrator role to be able to change password.
